# Copy redis database (.rdb file) from a remote server to local

Tags: redis, redis-cli, redis-server, redisclient

I was given a Redis server that is set up remotely.
I can access data in that and I can do CRUD operation with that server.
But I want the replica of the same database in my local.

I have Redis desktop manager setup in my local. And also redis-server setup running.

**Things I have tried:**

1. using **SAVE** command.

   I have connected to the remote server and executed save command. It ran 
   successfully and created `dump.rdb` file on that server. But I can't access that file as I don't have permission for server FTP.
2. using **BGSAVE**

   same scenario here also
3. using **redis-cli** command

   ```
   redis-cli -h server ip -p 6379 save > \\local ip\dump.rdb
   ```

   Here I got an error **The network name cannot be found.**

Can anyone please suggest me on how can I copy the `.rdb` file from the server to local?

Comment: So do you have an SSH access to the remote machine? You can mostly transfer files using it, too. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol

Comment: I don't think so.
Tried with **putty** and  **pscp**  commands to get access via SSH.
No luck.
Any other commands to access remote server?

Comment: No,
As I said earlier I use Redis desktop manger to connect.
A snippet of configuration is uploaded here : http://imgur.com/a/F56Oq
Apart from that I have redis-server installed in my machine which I use to run redis-cli commands.

Comment: if you can connect with redis-cli, you can use `redis-cli -h server --rdb dump.rdb` to have it save locally.

Comment: @ItamarHaber `redis-cli -h server --rdb dump.rdb` worked actually.
It has saved db in local.
But when i restarted db it is throwing this error : http://imgur.com/a/MHbS4
Any idea what is this about?

Comment: I'm guessing that the server you're running is of an older version than the one that the dump is from