# Batch / offline methods of converting RESP files to Redis RDB file

Tags: redis, batch-processing, offline, redis-cli

Assuming we want to automate the process of creating RDB files (and don't want to use Redis server for this purpose) what options are available?

---

The current process involves importing (with `redis-cli`) a set of RESP files to a Redis server and then saving a RDB file to disk (all that in a stateless Redis container, where the RDB file is not persistent and difficult to access automatically). The imported dictionaries are too large for automated data ingestion via a remote Redis python client (we have to import from files).

Answer (score 0):

If the question's restrictions are liberalized somewhat to not running a *local* `redis-server` (as opposed to no dependency on `any` Redis server), is becomes possible to save (or more precisely, download) a *remote* Redis server database to a local (client-side) RDB file by connecting from a local client (`redis-cli`) to a remote `redis-server` instance (as pointed out by Itamar Haber in a comment to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44645543/9962007)), like this:

```bash
redis-cli -h <REMOTE_URL> -p <REMOTE_PORT> --rdb <LOCAL_PATH>/dump.rdb
```

It is equally possible to use `redis-cli` to first ingest the data from local RESP files to a remote Redis server (in order to later re-export the data to a local RDB file, as described above).